# Trying to fill form with data from database and no data is being inserted

Tags: php, html, mysql, pdo

I am trying to write code that will take information from my sql database and insert it into html fields to be edited.

The database I am using contains

-postid int(10)

-title text

-author text

-date date

-content text

-tag1 and 2 both text

When I run error check the information I get back is "array(1) { [0]=> string(5) "00000" }" Is there anything in my code that anyone can see that would cause this? I am all out of ideas. Thank you in advance for any responses whether they solve the problem or not!

edit: I am also only using postid's that are actually in the database, so it is not from there being no information for said id in the database.

edit 2: different problem

```
<?php

include("connect.php");

$delete_message_query = $db->prepare("
    DELETE FROM `blogposts`
    WHERE `postid` = :id
    ")
$delete_message_query->execute(array(
    :id => $_GET["id"]
    )
);


header("Location: edit.php");

?>
```

Trying to use this code to delete a certain row.

```
     <?php
        $id = $_GET["id"];
          include ("connect.php");//database connection
          $get_blog_query = $db->prepare("
            SELECT * FROM `blogposts`
            WHERE `postid` = '$id'
            ");

          $get_blog_query->execute();




          ?>
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
    <html>
    <head>
    <title>Form Edit Data</title>
    </head>

    <body>
    <table border=1>
          <tr>
        <td align=center>Edit Blog Posts</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>
          <table>
          <form method="post" action="edit_data.php">
          <input type="hidden" name="id" value="<? echo "$row[postid]"?>">
            <tr>       
              <td>Title</td>
              <td>
                <input type="text" name="title"
            size="20" value="<? echo "$row[title]"?>">
              </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td>Author</td>
              <td>
                <input type="text" name="address" size="40"
              value="<? echo "$row[author]"?>">
              </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td>Content</td>
              <td>
                <textarea name='content' rows=10 cols=50 id='content'value="<? echo "$row[content]"?>"></textarea>


            </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td>Catagory 1</td>
              <td>
                <input type="text" name="address" size="40"
              value="<? echo "$row[tag1]"?>">
              </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td>Catagory 2</td>
              <td>
                <input type="text" name="address" size="40"
              value="<? echo "$row[tag2]"?>">
              </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td align="right">
                <input type="submit"
              name="submit value" value="Edit">
              </td>
            </tr>
          </form>
          </table>
        </td>
      </tr>
    </table>
    </body>
    </html>
```

Comment: Where is the code to populate $row?

Comment: What would I use to get that would it be something like  $row = $get_blog_query->fetch();

Comment: Why you're trying syntax you don't know how to use? There is an example in my answer. Follow it

Comment: To try and learn it :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For some reason you are not using prepared statements, while you should.
So, here is the code

```
 <?php
 include ("connect.php");//database connection
 $stmt = $db->prepare("SELECT * FROM `blogposts` WHERE `postid` = ?");
 $stmt->execute(array($_GET["id"]));
 $row = $stmt->fetch();
 ?>
```

Also note that `"$row[postid]"` is wrong syntax. It have to be `$row["postid"]` instead. Variables have to be addressed without quotes in PHP, while quotes have to be used to delimit strings only.

Also, every from value ought to be properly encoded. So, all this output have to be like this

```
<?=htmlspecialchars($row["postid"])?>
```

Comment: fetch() would only give you one row. Maybe $_GET["id"] should be sanitized before going into the execute() also.

Comment: Thank you! This worked for everything but the content area! Is there a difference between input areas and text areas in the syntax?

Comment: Nevermind I fixed it by echoing inside the area! Thank you so much for your help and quick reply!

Comment: @Chris sure. textarea has no value attribute. But output have to be the same as shown

Comment: If you could help with one more thing I would be forever grateful. I am trying to delete using a similar code but my execute statement is invalid I have edited the main post with the code.

Comment: I had the syntax wrong when I tried it your way the first time so I tried off a example I found. I tried it again and it worked. Sorry for the annoyance and thank you for the help!

Answer (score 0):

$row[postid] isn't a string, it is a variable and therefore does not need the quotation marks surrounding it. However the fields DO need escaping, so instead of "$row[title]", try $row['title']

Comment: "fields" do not need "escaping". Strings do.